# PackageManager's applicationInfo.name is always null

Tags: android, process

```
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(RunningAppProcessInfo process : runningAppProcesses) {
    try {
        ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(process.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Log.d(TAG, applicationInfo.name + "");
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`process.processName` returns a valid package name but `applicationInfo.name` is always null.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Used `applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManagerInstance)` to find the Application name, but there should be a reason why `applicationInfo.name` didn't work.

**Edit**

`applicationInfo.name` is the name of a `Application` subclass if you have any.

Comment: Thanks, this trick worked. applicationInfo.name doesn't work for me.

Comment: Me neither! :-X

Answer (score 8):

The reason name is null is that it really is... null.

Please refer to the Android manifest documentation:

> android:name The fully qualified name
> of an Application subclass implemented
> for the application. When the
> application process is started, this
> class is instantiated before any of
> the application's components.
>
> The
> subclass is optional; most
> applications won't need one. In the
> absence of a subclass, Android uses an
> instance of the base Application
> class.

What you want is the name of the application, which is set in the label attribute of the application tag, and which Ragunath explained how to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Log.d(TAG, ai.processName + "");
```

or this

```
Log.d(TAG, ai.packageName + "");
```

Comment: Works! but returns the package name, not the application name. Same as process.processName