# Getting time spend on each application Android?

Tags: android, mobile

1. Can we get how much time a user has spend on each application installed on his andorid?
2. Or which are the most frequently used applications ?
3. Also if we want to get the names ( not package names ) of all the applications what to do ?

   ```
   List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   String TAG = "yolo";
   String out = "";
   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.toString());
       pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
   }
   ```

I have the above code, but it gives me only package names, can I somehow get the name ? ( name by which application is installed )

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 3rd question, you want the application "label" -

```
packageInfo.loadLabel(pm)
```

See this post:

[PackageManager's applicationInfo.name is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021966/packagemanagers-applicationinfo-name-is-always-null)

Your other questions should be asked separately. They require very different answers, depending on how you want to implement them.