# Android packagemanager list causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am fairly new to Android programming. I downloaded Android Studio today and started a new project. I added an empty activity to the form with a textview with the following code.

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

MAIN CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
            PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> applications = pm.getInstalledApplications(flags);
    List<String> applicationsInstalled = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : applications) {
        if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
            // System application
        } else {
            // Installed by user
            applicationsInstalled.add(appInfo.name);
        }
    }
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    for (String app : applicationsInstalled)
    {
        tv1.append(app);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

For some reason, the app crashes as soon as it launches. If I remove the code I wrote and only keep till

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

it works fine but is empty.

EDIT: Stacktrace https://pastebin.com/dHHygFkQ

Comment: can you please edit and add your stacktrace?

Comment: @fbwnd I just added the stacktrace option to the command line (googled it, idk what it is). where do i see its output?

Comment: You can see it from the AndroidStudio. 
If you prefer the command line 
use: adb logcat -s AndroidRuntime
and paste the output (when it crashes) here

Comment: first of all you call setContentView() 2 times. remove the last one

Comment: @KostasDrak haha missed that, waited for the stack trace:)

Comment: @KostasDrak sorry im new and this maybe a stupid doubt but isnt the second one supposed to 'refresh' the view with the updated text?

Comment: updated with the stacktrace. i hope i did it right.

Comment: @KostasDrak i removed it - its still crashing

Comment: of course not....you are calling the layout twice. if you want to update the layout you will have to use runOnUiThread() which accepts a Runnable and in there you will update the UI

Comment: updated stacktrace with the oen from android monitor in the IDE @fbwnd

Comment: where do you try to get the length of something?

Comment: I just noticed that part in the stack. That's the thing - I don't. This code is all I have for now and I am just messing around with lists.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: For now, getting the list of third party user installed apps on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, remove the second setContentView.

You are passing `null` to `tv1.append`. As `appInfo.name` returns `null`. See [PackageManager's applicationInfo.name is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021966/packagemanagers-applicationinfo-name-is-always-null)

Use:
`(String)pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo)`.

For example:

`applicationsInstalled.add((String)pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo))`

Comment: this will only get the current application label

Comment: @KostasDrak Not according to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)

Comment: @Haardik I would recommend to verify that pm.getApplicationLabel(appInfo) isn't null before adding to the list.

Comment: @fbwnd I'll do that, thanks. But if i may ask, why would it ever be null?

Comment: It shouldn't be, though, as mentioned in the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationLabel(android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo)). It can be